# Spring Data JPA: findAll with Specification and Pageable fails on count query

Tags: java, count, spring-data-jpa, fetch, specifications

I'm trying to fetch some data on the `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` of JpaSpecificationExecutor.

My spec is:

```
public static Specification<Report> isTemplate(boolean isTemplate) {
    return (root, query, cb) ->{
            root.fetch("entity1");
            root.fetch("entity2");
            root.fetch("entity3");
            root.fetch("entity4");
            root.fetch("entity5");
            return cb.equal(root.get("isTemplate"), isTemplate);
        }; 
}
```

Where report has 5 subtables(entity1...) that had a relation one to one with report.

Here is an example of a getter of one of his relations:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "report")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
public Entity1 getEntity1() {
    return this.entity1;
}
```

Now, when I call `List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec)` with my specs everything works fine. But when I call the `Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)` fails when reach the count query giving the next exception:

> "exception":
>   "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
>   "message": "org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join
>   fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in
>   the select list... [select count(generatedAlias0) from
>   com.xxx.yyy.editor.entity.Report as generatedAlias0 inner join fetch
>   generatedAlias0.report1 as generatedAlias1 inner join fetch
>   generatedAlias0.report2 as generatedAlias2..."

Any one else face this issue or know why this could be happen.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Thank you in advance.

PD. I'm using fetch to get all the relation in one query.

Answer (score 4):

I faced with the same issue as you. The problem here is when paging, it will call a count query, but the count query doesn't allow fetch.

To overcome this problem, we have to prevent fetch when counting by checking result type of the query and only fetch if the result type is not long (when result type is long, it means the count query executed) as below:

```
public static Specification<Report> isTemplate(boolean isTemplate) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        if (query.getResultType() != Long.class && query.getResultType() != long.class) {
            root.fetch("entity1");
            root.fetch("entity2");
            root.fetch("entity3");
            root.fetch("entity4");
            root.fetch("entity5");
        }
        return cb.equal(root.get("isTemplate"), isTemplate);
    };
```

}

You can refer following articles:

- https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/fetch-query-not-working-spring-data-jpa-pageable
- https://coderanch.com/t/656073/frameworks/Spring-Data-fetch-join-Specification

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

i recently had a problem with the count query failing as well. i was using a heavily modified version of Carl Mapada's Advanced Search and Filtering code that i adapted. my (jpa) Specification was complex, built with many dynamic on-the-fly SpecificationS that were combined. i was using jpa data 2.2.7.

myRepository.findAll(spec) worked just fine
but
myRepository.findAll(spec, pageable) did not.

here is the solution i went with after realizing that the same Specification instance couldn't be used twice (once for the count query and once to get the data) at least in my case...

```
// CustomRepositoryImpl.java (public methods here are in CustomRepository.java)
@NoRepositoryBean
public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long>
    implements CustomRepository<T, Long {

    private EntityManager em;

    public CustomRepositoryImpl(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<T, Long> entityInfo, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityInfo, em);
        this.em = em;
    }

    public CustomImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
    }


    public Page<T> findAll(SpecificationBuilder<T> builder, Pageable pageable, EntityGraphType entityGraphType, String entityGraphName) {

        long count = this.count(builder.build());
        //OR for more control...
        // TypedQuery<Long> countQuery = getCountQuery(builder.build(), getDomainClass());
        // countQuery.setHint(EntityGraphType.FETCH.getKey(), countEntityGraphNameCouldBePassedInToMethodIfDesired);
        // long count = countQuery.getSingleResult();

        // need a diff instance of the Specification for some reason
        Specification<T> spec = builder.build();
        TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, Sort.unsorted());
        query.setHint(entityGraphType.getKey(), em.getEntityGraph(entityGraph));
        return readPage(query, pageable, (int) count);
    }

    public Page<T> findAll(SpecificationBuilder<T> builder, Pageable pageable, String entityGraphName) {  
        return this.findAll(builder, pageable, EnitityGraphType.FETCH, entityGraphName);
    }

    private <S extends T> Page<S> readPage(TypedQuery<S> query, Pageable pageable, int count) {
        query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
        query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

        List<S> content = query.getResultList();
        return new PageImpl<S>(content, pageable, count);
    }
}


// SpecificationBuilder.java
public interface SpecificationBuilder<T> {
    Specification<T> build();
}



// MyEntitySpecificationBuilder.java
// search for Advanced Search and Filtering on the internet for more details
public class MyEntitySpecificationBuilder implements SpecificationBuilder<MyEntity> {

    public Specification<MyEntity> build() {
        ...
    }
}
```